# Why do I see "No Debuggable Applications" in Android Studio Logcat while my application is running?

Tags: android-studio, logcat

I wanted to filter what is shown in the Android Studio Logcat to show what is relevant to my application only. I have chosen `Show only selected applications` from the drop down at the top of the logcat as shown in the following screenshot:

[image: Android Studio Logcat Screenshot]

But in the drop down menu above it which is supposed to show running application(s) (and other options) from which we can choose our application to see Log messages related to it only, I see `No debuggable Applications` as the only option.

[image: Android Studio Logcat Screenshot]

**Why? What should I do to fix this?**

***Note:*** It does not happen every time I run the project. Sometimes it happens, sometimes it automatically selects my app (when I run it) from the drop down menu shown in the second screenshot, and filters the results properly.

Comment: You should read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26593927/android-studio-no-debuggable-applications

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Open Android Studio, Go to,

> Tools-> Android -> Enable ADB Integration.

Open Android Monitor,

After enabling that, everything should work properly and you can see your package name of your application.

Comment: this doesn't help in v1.3.1, where this is enabled by default..I'm still trying to get an emulator to run on first install

Comment: I am having troubles with this now, except `ADB Integration` was already enabled. I tried disabling and running, then rebuilding, and then re-inalienably but still nothing.

Comment: Try ADB Integration disable and then enable again if already enabled, disconnect device, clean project, reconnect device and rerun.

Answer (score 7):

With v1.3.1 I disabled & enabled again "Enable ADB Integration" and it worked.

Answer (score 4):

Go to Android Studio, Tools, Android, Disable ADB Integration and Enable it again. Make sure you clean your project before running !

Answer (score 3):

Just click on 'debug icon'(BUG icon) next to 'run icon'(Arrow icon) then u can see app in logcat

Comment: this is much better!

Answer (score 3):

This helped me:

1)Disconnect device

2)Kill adb from taskmanager

3)Clean project

4)Connect device

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have your **DDMS window closed**.
If it is open, your logs might be visible there but not in Android Studio.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I used to use *2 Android Studio's* (stable and canary) so the reason of the problem was this.

So, if you are running another IDE such as another **Android Studio** or **Eclipse** this could be the problem.

**Solution**: Close one of the IDE and if "Enable ADB Integration" is already enabled disabling and re-enabling solves it

Answer (score 2):

For me it was a case of changing the `build.gradle` file to:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        debuggable true
        ...
        ...
}
```

`Project sync` then the app should appear in the menu which previously only had `No debuggable applications`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. [image]  As in this picture, instead of "app", it was class name. So click it and select "app" and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

> Please make sure to have the android property `debuggable = "true"` in the application tag AndroidManifest.xml

```
**<application  android:debuggable="true"> 
</application>**
```

Also, if you have multiple build variants (ex. debug, alpha, release) you may need to check which build you are attempting to debug and set the `debuggable true` attribute accordingly in the **build.gradle**

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        ...
        debuggable true
        ...
    }
    alpha {
        ...
        debuggable true
        ...
    }
    release {
        ...
        debuggable false
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that emulators worked fine with solutions listed above, but my real device never did. Eventually some log came up saying I needed to add the debug flag to my manifest. Since I am using project flavors, it was easy enough to add this to my debug build variant in my gradle file. However, you could also manually add the flag to the manifest as needed - just make sure to not have it there in a production app version.

Answer (score 0):

you should make share your IDE(Intellij or AS) **Build Variants settings**

[there is a simple](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42661480/1528524)