# Android monitor not showing application

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, xamarin

I have created a xamarin forms application and started the debug process from Visual studio.

I would like to be able to use the "Android Monitor" tools in android studio I.E.

- Memory
- CPU
- Network
- GPU

But i **cannot** see my app in the drop down e.g. my.app.android

[image]

Is what I am trying to do possible? I feel it should be. I have tried all the suggestions on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30855962/why-do-i-see-no-debuggable-applications-in-android-studio-logcat-while-my-appl) and others but with no success. Currently if I select one of the items in the drop down I some data from memory, CPU etc, but that's obviously not to helpful as i'm not getting any specifics about my app.

I can successfully view data about my device by using "Android Device Monitor", but I feel like i'm missing out on some vital information not having "Android Monitor" tools

Comment: Not sure if this is the issue but I have noticed that Instant Run causes this kind of issues, try disabling Instant Run - uninstall and install/run again.

Comment: This is probably a really stupid question, do you mean first try and disable instant run and if that doesn't work try uninstall android studio?

Comment: No what I meant is to disable instant run then uninstall the application from the emulator/device then installing the application again.

Comment: try to force "debuggable true" in your build.gradle... just to see if you have a different result

Comment: @H.Brooks that worked perfectly for everything except GPU, is there something that could be stopping that? put your comment as the answer and I will accept it

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/a/35169716/2826147

Comment: @AmitVaghela Like he said, he already turned off instant run (this fixed his issue) and I have already posted a answer on how to do it for future readers and I also posted how to fix the GPU issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have noticed that Instant Run causes this kind of issues. 
Try turning off instant run:

**Mac**
- Android Studio > Preferences > Build, execution, deploy > Instant Run.

**Windows**
- File > Setting

In regards to the GPU issue, the documentation states the following:

> To enable GPU monitoring, make sure you turn on monitoring for your Android hardware device or emulator under Setting → Developer Options → Profile GPU rendering → In adb shell dumpsys gfxinfo

One you enabled GPU rendering in adb shell dumpsys gfxinfo, you have to untoggle the pause icon in Android Studio (on the left of the graph) for the GPU profiling to start for the selected app.

Hope this helps.