# android app not appearing on smartphone

Tags: android, smartphone

I have tried and tried to put my app on my phone.  I have done all the adjusting things recommended on other sites for my phone.  I've taken care of many other problems.  When I do Run Edit->Configurations USB choice, it's doing something because I can see the 6:Android comments running.  It's just it never appears on my phone. My best guess is that this may be because above the 6:Android bar statement printer next to the kind of my phone says, "No Debuggable Applications" in red.  That's my best guess as to what is wrong.

To fix this:  I tried Tools->Android->Enable ADB.  At [Android Studio - no debuggable applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26593927/android-studio-no-debuggable-applications), they suggest the solution is to "turn on debuggable flag (debuggable true) in application's gradle file:"  However, I have multiple gradle files, and I'm searched all of them for the statements mentioned to be  in the gradle file and not one was there.

Any help troubleshooting?  Any more info I should provide?

Done (general):
pretty sure did everything for phone (don't remember exactly, followed lists from other websites)
installed and changed path to git.exe
changed stuff to UT-8 file format
downloaded device driver for phone
looked for quote in gradle files
made sure added apk
Tools->Android->Enable ADB (checked, unchecked and rechecked)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out:

your sdk was not in your path

I had to put the file location of my sdk in my environmental variable PATH.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to run the app you developed from AndroidStudio on your Phone. If yes, then try these.

1. Have you turned on USB Debugging from DeveloperOptions in your Mobiles settings ?
2. Is your  device connected to your PC, is detected ?
3. Did it ask for Enable USB Debuging , when coonected to PC ?

These should solve ur problem.

Comment: Did all of those.  Should've listed them.