# Android Studio -- Logcat showing "no connected devices" and "no debuggable applications"

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat

I'm using Android Studio and logcat shows no output; it just says "no connected devices" and "no debuggable applications" (see picture below).

I know that this sounds like a duplicate, but I've tried answers from other questions (e.g. [Android Studio - no debuggable applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26593927/android-studio-no-debuggable-applications)) and it didn't help:  I enabled ADB Integration,  set the debuggable flag in the gradle file, closed Eclipse and restarted both Android Studio and my computer a few times.

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: is this when your phone is plugged in? Have you enabled debugging on your device, and for that matter what device is it?

Comment: No, it's an Android Virtual Device. Which _seems_ to be correctly configured, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 2):

You can try restarting the adb server as root.

`sudo adb kill-server && sudo adb start-server`