# Android multiple process running

Tags: android

[image]

Multiple process running in single application. How to avoid this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

> The Android SDK provides most of the tools that you need to debug your
>   applications. You need a JDWP-compliant debugger if you want to be
>   able to do things such as step through code, view variable values, and
>   pause execution of an application. If you are using Android Studio, a
>   JDWP-compliant debugger is already included and there is no setup
>   required. If you are using another IDE, you can use the debugger that
>   comes with it and attach the debugger to a special port so it can
>   communicate with the application VMs on your devices.

[image]

**Tools-> Android -> ADB Integration.**

**or**

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        debuggable false // boolean
    }
}
```

Go through **[Android Studio - no debuggable applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26593927/android-studio-no-debuggable-applications)**