# Android USB Debugging is not working on my phone as the application isn't installing on my phone

Tags: android, usb-debugging

I recently bought a phone Coolpad Note 3 Lite and enabled USB Debugging on my phone. When I run the application on Android Studio on Ubuntu it can recognise my device as you can see in this picture:

[image: picture]

But once the gradle build is completed then the application doesn't run on my phone and "Run" window looks like this:

[image: picture]

Previously I used a Motorola Device and usb Debugging worked flawlessly but with new device USB Debugging isn't working.

I work with a Ubuntu Installed laptop

Comment: If you click on "No Debuggable Applications", do you see your app?

Comment: @cricket_007 maybe the part that says "No debuggable applications"?

Comment: Maybe related:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26593927/android-studio-no-debuggable-applications

Comment: @chessdork No I don't see my when I click on "No Debuggable Applications"

Comment: cricket_007 answers on that question are not working :/

Comment: Looks like your USB debugging works fine, as your phone shows up in the dropdown in "Android Monitor" tool window. What output do you see  in "Run" tool window?

Comment: @MarcinKoziński "Run" tool window says "Client not ready yet.."

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled USB tethering? You may need to restart your Android Studio or machine once you do.

Comment: but we use debug in MTP mode, don't we ?

Comment: Yes,the basic idea is to give access to files on your Android device. What worked for me was to uncheck USB debuggable on the phone,enable USB tethering, restart phone and machine.Reconnect the phone, check the USB debugging option again on the developer option tab. It brings up the RSA key pop up. All ok after that.

Comment: Its not working even after trying what you recommended.
The run window says "Client not ready yet..."